# Redirect to https when detect mobile or tablet

Tags: redirect, mobile, https

i want to redirect to https when detect mobile or teblet but not pc/laptap. on pc and laptops i want to use plan http. i try bellow htaccess code but its redirecting to https on all mobile/tablet/pc/laptop devices.

i also try mobile detect php script but i can't success.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: May I ask why you want to left pc/laptops users insecure? Furthermore, because of that you can't use HSTS+preload, the only real protection against MITM

Comment: http is fast than https and we are living in Pakistan and most users come from mobile devices using cellular network and our cellular network injecting popup under ads on non https websites. so i want to redirect mobile users to https..

Comment: With spdy/http2 https is faster than http. You should try it : https://www.httpvshttps.com/

Comment: Thank You @Tom got it.. https is faster....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check mobile device in apache and redirect to mobile website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358530/check-mobile-device-in-apache-and-redirect-to-mobile-website)