# React redirect to mobile site

Tags: reactjs

On my react app I need to redirect mobile users to the mobile site. When someone goes to my url for example: `example.com`, if they are on mobile, I need the url to redirect to `mobile.example.com`. I havent found any good articles on file structures for a react app like this that has a mobile view and a desktop view. I also need to test it on localhost. I am using `react-router-dom` for routing as well couldnt find anything on changing the baseurl to mobile either.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you check this out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent. These days , most websites are single page apps and are built to work on both device types (it's a little more elegant), but you can try and divine it by measuring screen  width, user agent and so on

To answer your comment, you could do something like

```
if (navigator.userAgent.contains('....your mobile user agent type') 
{
location.replace('http://m.mymobilesite.com')
}
```

Comment: I am trying to go for the same effect as facebook or twitter. When I go to twitter.com on my phone it goes directly to mobile.twitter.com. My goal is to keep the same app (I dont want 2 versions of the app). Just simplified pages for mobile

Comment: typically you use media queries and so on to have a single code base that gracefully renders at different resolutions, hiding elements and simplifying at smaller resolutions etc.

Comment: Yes but is it possible to redirect to the mobile prefix for the baseurl using react-router-dom or just plain js/html?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache you can check this post:
[Check mobile device in apache and redirect to mobile website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358530/check-mobile-device-in-apache-and-redirect-to-mobile-website)

If you are using Node you can use Apache as proxy and redirect to your Node server

To answer to your comment you can just use this library:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-device-detect

```js
import { isMobile } from 'react-device-detect';
import  { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

//...

export default class App extends Component {
    //...
    render() {
        return isMobile ? <Redirect to='mobile-site'/> : <Redirect to='desktop-site'/>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that I dont need to access any deployment settings and just change the settings in the html code of my react app instead? I dont have access to deployments

Comment: Yes, you can check the User-Agent directly in your code and redirect, just make sure that you do it in every page, if your application starts always from the same file(like an index file) you just need to add the control as first instruction

Comment: How can I do it using react? I know how to check for user device just dont know how to change the prefix of `example.com` into `mobile.example.com`

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it

Comment: You didnt understand my question, redirect component deals with the pathname. I need to change the hostname.

Comment: "prefix of `example.com` into `mobile.example.com`"

Comment: You cannot do that, you need to have two different routing structure(one per subdomain),you cannot call external links with react-router-dom, a subdomain is indipendent from the others, you can try to move the mobile subdomain to example.com/mobile otherwise you need to have two different routing strategies like two indipendent apps